# How many draws do I need to fill $n$ slots?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a discrete random variable R with $n$ equally distributed possible outcomes. How many times do I need to draw from the distribution to have a $p\%$ chance of having seen every outcome at least once?

Bonus question: what if R is not equally distributed?

Background: In Denmark, the Tuborg brewery has released a Christmas beer edition with numbers from 1-24 printed on the cans. We're not sure whether the numbers are equally distributed (they probably aren't). How many beers will we have to drink to have a 95% percent chance of getting every number?

Comment: See the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: The Beer question cannot be answered without the distribution of the numbers (i.e., for every answer that you give me, I can give you a distribution under which your answer will not suffice for $95\%$ confidence of seeing all numbers).